# Matrix multiplication in C script

Tags: arrays, c

Hey StackOverflow community!

I need some of your attention and help. I have an assignment to create a Matrix multiplication but the problem is that the code get's stuck after input first dimension of an array. It won't pass the argument to the second dimension B.

Here is the code:

```
int main()
{
    int k, n, m;
    printf("Dimensions for A array: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &k);
    int A[n][k];
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        for (int r = 0; r<k; r++) {
            scanf("%d", &A[i][r]);
        }
    }
    printf("Dimensions for B array: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &k, &m);

    int B[k][m];
    for (int i = 0; i<k; i++) {
        for (int r = 0; r<m; r++) {
            scanf("%d", &B[i][r]);
        }
    }
    if (n != m) {

        int C[0][0];
    }
    else {
        int total;
        int C[n][m];
        for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
            for (int l = 0; l<m; l++) {
                for (int g = 0; g<k; g++) {
                    total += A[i][g] * B[g][l];
                }
                C[i][l] = total;
                total = 0;
            }

        }
        for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
            for (int c = 0; c<m; c++) {
                printf("%d    ", C[i][c]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

The goal I am trying to achieve with this script:

Input format:

Line 1: Two space-separated integers, n and k.

Line 2 to n+1: line i+1 contains k space-separated integers: row i of matrix A.

Line n+2: Two space-separated integers, k and m.

Line n+3 to n+k+4: Line i+n+3 contains m space-separated integers: row i of matrix B.

Sample Input:

```
    1 2

    4 5 1
```

Output format:

Line 1: two space-separated n and m, the dimension of matrix C.

Line 2 to m+1: Line i+1 contains m space-separated integers: row i of matrix C.

Sample Output:

```
    2 4 4

    1 1
```

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: There better be a lot more input that what you're showing us. There is *barely* even one matrix there much less the dimensions and flesh of a second. Frankly, I'd start by coding your input IO to ensure you actually read valid data and not just blindly assume all IO works 100% of the time as hoped. You have four critical `scanf` points in this code, and exactly *none* of them are ever checked for validation and proper ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scanf("%d %d", &n, &k);

scanf("%d %d", &k, &m);
```

You're overwriting the `k` variable so you no longer know the dimensions of the first array. Since you're using uppercase letters for the matrics, I suggest `a,b,c,d` for the dimensions.

```
if (n != m) {

    int C[0][0];
}
else {
```

Matrices are compatible if the *inner* dimensions are equal (`b != c` if you use the names suggested above). Also, you might want to print a message in this branch so you can follow what's happening from the output.

And one small remark: C is not a *scripting* language. This is a *program*, not a script.